# how to pysimplegui manage dataframe in excel?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, pysimplegui

i want to delete dataframe unnamed in red arrow , and the i want to add some text when i click submit i have index from 1 not in 0 like this

[Data_entry.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyEpg.png)

can you give me solution about this problem ?

in above my code in python 3

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl
 
# Give the location of the file
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\WEB\\PYTHON_PYSIMPLEGUI\\Data_Entry.xlsx"


sg.theme('DarkGreen7')


EXCEL_FILE = 'Data_Entry.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

my_img = sg.Image(r'C:\Users\master\Desktop\WEB\PYTHON_PYSIMPLEGUI\logo.png')

"""
# Template Taskbar

menu_def = [['File', ['Open', 'Save', 'Exit',]],
                ['Edit', ['Paste', ['Special', 'Normal',], 'Undo'],],
                ['Help', 'About...'],]
"""





menu_def = [['File', ['Exit']],['Help', 'About...'],]


layout = [
    [sg.Menu(menu_def)],
    [sg.Column([[my_img]], justification='center')],
    [sg.Text('Simacan ( SIstem Monitoring And Controling Absen Nilai')],
    [sg.Text('Nama', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Nama')],
    [sg.Text('Kehadiran', size=(15,1)), sg.Combo(['Hadir', 'Sakit', 'Tidak Masuk'], key='Keterangan')],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Exit()]
    ]
    

window =sg.Window('Aplikasi Simacan versi 1.2', layout,size=(800, 600), font='Courier 12')


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Submit':
        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=True)
        sg.popup('Data saved !')
        print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's are some issues here.

- Create a blank excel file to store your data.
- Open excel file as a dataframe, option `index_col` set the index column or you may get `Unnamed: 0` column as index in your dataframe.

```py
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index_col=[0])
```

- There's one extra item `0` in dictionary `values`, it is the key of sg.Menu, should remove it before you append the `values` to your dataframe by

```py
del values[0]
```

- You can re-index your dataframe by

```py
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
```

- You can save dataframe to your excel file only before end of you script, of course, write each new record to your excel file is still fine.